# Initial UIviewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I started to create tabBarApplication and now I need to set new UIViewController  that i created as initial.It's a new controller, doesn't belong to tabBar ViewControllers.  I'm not using storyboards.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: ok. I started to do using tabBar and now I want other UIViewController to be initial. What I have to do to set my UIViewController as initial?

Comment: I have improved my answer to show you where to change the first screen displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a UINavigationController as a base for the app, having your initial view as root view controller and then pushing the tabView when necessary.

To set the main view controller edit your AppDelegate.m file

```
UIWindow *win = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

/* here you should create your controller and asign it to the variable named controller */

[win addSubview:controller.view];
[win makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I believe you cannot push a tabBar controller into a navigation controller so you will probably have to embed the tab bar into another view. I have done something like this in my app.